# React-toastify: Specify custom width for .Toastify__toast-container--top-center

Tags: reactjs, react-toastify

In React-Toastify, if I do

```
toast(<Alert id="alert" type="error" heading="Error" headingLevel='h1' children={msg} />, 
   { className: "toastError" });
```

that puts the CSS `toastError` on the wrong DIV for me. My class defines a custom width of 640px. You can see that the class gets applied to the `div id="5"` and that doesn't give me the correct width. My width only works when 640px is applied to the **parent** of that DIV, which is `Toastify__toast-container--top-center`.

```
<div class="Toastify__toast-container Toastify__toast-container--top-center" /* NEED IT HERE!*/>
   <div id="5" class="Toastify__toast Toastify__toast-theme--light Toastify__toast--default Toastify__toast--close-on-click toastError" style="background-color: rgb(236, 243, 236);
```

I need to specifically and conditionally target that top DIV. Also, other toast messages should **not** have an overridden width because of this. This custom width only applies in one single case. Is there a way to achieve this?

The width does work if defined on the `<ToastContainer style={{width:640}}.../>` level. But I don't want to define it there because I want to keep different widths for different toast messages that use the same ToastContainer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to the following CSS workaround:

```
.Toastify__toast-container--top-center:has(div.toastError) {
    width: 640px;
}
```

This will modify the width of the correct Parent DIV (`.Toastify__toast-container--top-center`) but only if its Child DIV contains the class passed with `toast()` in

```
toast(<Alert id="alert" type="error" heading="Error" headingLevel='h1' children={msg} />, 
   { className: "toastError" });
```

All other toasts in the `<ToastContainer>` will be undisturbed and have other widths. That's the only way I could find to target the correct Parent DIV but keep the widths different for different toast messages.

To the developers of `react-toastify`: You guys need to expose one more property, in addition to the 2 you already expose, that would be the outermost `--top-center` container:

```
  className: "className1",
  bodyClassName: "className2",
  topParentClassName: "className3" /* This is my own proposal for easy Top-Parent styling */
```